# Sorting a mixed text-numeric matrix (cell array) by one of its (numeric) columns

Tags: matlab

I have an Excel spreadsheet whose rows I'd like to randomly shuffle and further use in Matlab. To that end, I'm reading the XLS into a cell array, generating random numbers into a column, then sorting by that column. This is proving to be problematic though, because of conflicting variable types. The code I used is:

```
[num, txt, M] = xlsread(fileName);
for row=2:row_N % generate random numbers in the D column
    M(row,4) = num2cell(rand);
end
M = sortrows(M,4);
```

This leads to my matrix looking like this:

[image]

Because the D column contains numbers while there's text in the other columns, the sorting cannot be done (it says "Cell elements must be character arrays.").

I tried various conversions between numeric and cell variables, and also tried using 'readtable' instead of 'xlsread' - but there is always a problem, such that I cannot get this conflict solved. Any suggestions? Using Matlab 2016a.

Comment: The first row of `M` contains headers, try `sortrows(M(2:end,:),4)`. I suggest to remove the header from `M` (`M = M(2:end,:)`) and store these separate if needed.

Comment: You can read the xls as a `table`, which might be easier to work with (see: [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) and [`importdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)).

Comment: Thanks @rinkert the header row was indeed the problem. I'd have thought it's fine since there were anyway other strings in the matrix, but I realise the problem was there was a string in the very header of the D column.

Comment: @z8080 yeah, there wouldn't have been an error if you used another column for sorting, but then this header would be seen as part of the data to sort, and end up somewhere (lexicographic order)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your goal, I think this does it. You may get different fieldnames from importdata and will have to change those, but assuming you don't this should cover it.

```
% import the data
impdata=importdata('temp.xlsx');

% get rid of the headers
oldcellarray=impdata.textdata(2:end,:);

%resort the rows in a random order
newcellarray=oldcellarray(randperm(size(oldcellarray,1)),:);
```